# Visual studio team services powershell get-content wrong path

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have issue with powershell script that replace values in js script, its working well on my windows power shell, but in vsts its failed.

```
(Get-Content -Path ‪*\Portal\app\app.js).replace('http://localhost:9941/signalr', 'random adress') | Set-Content -Path *\Portal\app\app.js
(Get-Content -Path ‪*\Portal\app\app.js).replace('http://localhost:39828/#/login', 'random adress') | Set-Content -Path *\Portal\app\app.js
```

In build on cloud its given me error

```
Get-Content : An object at the specified path ?*\Portal\app\app.js does not exist, or has been filtered by the 
-Include or -Exclude parameter. At C:\a\1\s\Trunk\FullSolutionBuildPS.ps1:1 char:2
+ (Get-Content -Path ?*\Portal\app\app.js).replace('http://localhost:9941/signalr' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Also i tried to get path without *, just whole path to file.

```
(Get-Content ‪C:\a\1\s\Trunk\Portal\app\app.js).replace('http://localhost:9941/signalr', 'random site') | Set-Content C:\a\1\s\Trunk\Portal\app\app.js
```

And its given me error with encoding, i'm not sure.

```
Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'â?ªC' does not exist.
At C:\a\1\s\Trunk\FullSolutionBuildPS.ps1:1 char:2
+ (Get-Content â?ªC:\a\1\s\Trunk\Portal\app\app.js).replace('http://localhost:9941 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (â?ªC:String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Comment: Shouldn't you quote your paths: "*\Portal\app\app.js"

Comment: I trying with that too, its given error like this: 
Get-Content : An object at the specified path ?*\Portal\app\app.js does not exist, or has been filtered by the 
-Include or -Exclude parameter.
At C:\a\1\s\Trunk\FullSolutionBuildPS.ps1:1 char:2
+ (Get-Content -Path "?*\Portal\app\app.js").replace('http://localhost:9941/signal ...

Comment: Your strings have `U+202A` Unicode character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with a similar powershell script on my side, but couldn't reproduce your issue, the script is working:

```
(Get-Content  C:\a\1\s\TestCaseProject\1\2\app.txt).replace('http://localhost:9941/signalr', 'random adress') | Set-Content C:\a\1\s\TestCaseProject\1\2\app.txt
```

According to your log, you keep receiving strange character between `Get-Content` and the path. But I don't receive any messy characters.

I'm posting what I tried for your reference. I only add one step in build, and map to $/teamproject in Repositity, then select the script:

[image]

You may create a light team project to reproduce this issue, check what will happen.